# Can Grafana in the same graph choose different measurement that is in influxdb with a different time range?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I want to achieve this goal as below:
  When i choose a 'last 24 hours' time range, the graph can get data from measurement A in the Influxdb. Then, when i choose the 'last 1 year' time range,The same graph can get data from measurement B in the Influxdb. The reason is that there is a large amount of data in one year.
Can granfana do it  or are there other  optional solutions?

Comment: This process should be automated in influxdb if you are using [downsampling](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/guides/downsampling_and_retention/) in your retention policy

Comment: But I can not choose the different measurement with a different time range

Answer (score 1):

No, this behavior has been asked for in several github issues but hasn't been solved yet.

Best workaround I've been able to find this far is [this comment](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/4262#issuecomment-475570324) by [talek](https://github.com/talek).

First make a measurement that has the information of your retention policies, for example called `rp_config`:

```
select * from forever.rp_config
name: rp_config
time                           end           idx rp      start
----                           ---           --- --      -----
1677-09-21T00:12:43.145224194Z 3600000       1   autogen 0
1677-09-21T00:12:43.145224194Z 3110400000000 4   y       2592000000
1677-09-21T00:12:43.145224194Z 2592000000    3   m       86400000
1677-09-21T00:12:43.145224194Z 86400000      2   d       3600000
```

Then define a variable in grafana, take the value from this measurement and recalculate the variable on each time range change:
[image: Grafana variable config]

The `$rp` variable should change its value according to the time range interval selected in the dashboard.

Then, it's just a matter of prefixing all measurements with the `$rp` variable.